# Grid view using arraylist in android

Tags: android

How to show the gridview data's using array list

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume, that you have an ArrayList: `values`;
In your `GridView`'s adapter you override the `getView` method:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    convertView = new TextView(parent.getContext());
    // you can also inflate, if your cell has a more complex layout:
    // convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_cell, parent, false);
    ((TextView)convertView).setText(values.get(position));
    // or if you've inflated your convertView, select it's text view and add the text to it:
    // ((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.cell)).setText(values.get(position));
    return convertView;
}
```